# Symfony 2 on vagrant virtualbox laravel/homestead different results on 2 systems, one still needs intl extension

Tags: vagrant, homestead, intl, symfony-2.8

I am getting something really weird.

So I use Laravel projects with vagrant already. But I need to install Symfony2. 
Therefore I adapt my Homestead.yaml files on both PC and Laptop(both systems running Linux Mint 17.3, KDE). I added the latest vagrant box add laravel/homestead, which is atm 0.5.0 on both systems.

Homestead.yaml then looks on both systems like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    -(laravel projects)
    - map: pma.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/phpMyAdmin-4.6.0-english/
    - map: symfony.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/symfony/web/
      type: symfony

databases:
    - symfony
```

Then I add as root in the /etc/hosts file the following line like this on both systems.

```
192.168.10.10   other-laravel-projects.local pma.local symfony.local
```

After that I vagrant up && vagrant ssh. As vagrant, I do

```
$ sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ symfony new symfony 2.8
```

After that, I still cannot access the http://symfony.local/config.php. So I add my IP address, which I can figure out via

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

in /web/config.php

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
    'my.ip.address.1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

Then I can finally access http://symfony.local/config.php. The problem is on my PC symfony's Configuration Checker says **All checks passed successfully. Your system is ready to run Symfony applications.**

But on my laptop, symfony's Configuration Checker says
RECOMMENDATIONS
To enhance your Symfony experience, it's recommended that you fix the following:

1. intl extension should be available
   Install and enable the **intl** extension (used for validators).

I tried composer require symfony/intl first, which did not fix it. Then I looked for php.ini files. The PC box has /etc/php 5.5/5.6/7.0 folders, whereas the laptop box only has 5.6/7.0, but not sure, whether that's it. Shouldn't they be the same anyway, isn't that the purpose of the boxes, to provide the same setup?

Comment: [Creating a symfony development environment with vagrant](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/igtq/creating-a-symfony-development-environment-with-vagrant) - it it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but updating the whole components involved solved it. I would delete it, but maybe someone finds it useful. Your link looks like fun though. Thankfully I don't have to work through it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had an outdated vagrant or virtualbox installation or an outdated Homestead folder(https://github.com/laravel/homestead) on laptop, which led to the failed config check.

Checklist: 
 1. Update vagrant
 2. Update provider(e.g. virtualbox)
 3. Update Homestead folder
 4. Check ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml and /etc/hosts
 5. Update vagrant box outdated

Changing Homestead.yaml needs vagrant provision to take effect, when the box is already running.